# get specific value from file_get_content

Tags: php

hi i need to get specific content from the file get content but the problem is if i made a function which determine the content of a page and when i call this function in a loop (means more than 200 times) than memory limit problem occur . i have resolve this problem by increase the memory limit by ini_set .
                                        My Question is that how can i increase the performance of this function.should i use ob_flush after reading the content or there is another way .please let me know .
thnks

Comment: Nobody can answer your question without seeing some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`file_get_contents()` reads the entire file into memory, which could be a problem when working on large files.

You could consider using the [`fopen()`](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) family of functions, which are more memory friendly.

Comment: thnks i have try this also. but never mind my code running on server fine there is no any problem .

Answer (score 0):

After getting contents of the site using file_get_contents() use mb_split() function to get the contents of the file as an array of words.